# Quiero mandar el valor que obtuve en ql query a un input text

Tags: javascript, jquery

este es mi codigo de query donde obtengo la diferencia de dos fechas y se guarda el valor en contdias lo comprobe con un alert y si obtine la diferencia pero yo quiere que ese valor lo mande en input text

```
function calcular() {
    var fechaini = new Date(document.getElementById('fechaini').value);
    var fechafin = new Date(document.getElementById('fechafin').value);
    var diasdif = fechafin.getTime() - fechaini.getTime();
    var contdias = Math.round(diasdif / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    if ((new Date(fechaini).getTime() > new Date(fechafin).getTime()))
    {
        alert('la fecha es menor');
        return false;
    } else {
        $('#dias').val(contdias);
        return true;
    }

}
```

aqui abajo esta mi codigo jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF8">
        <script src="js/newjavascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form >
        <input type="date" id="fechaini">
        <input type="date" id="fechafin">
        <input type="text" id="dias" value="0">

       <input type="button" value="enviar" onclick="calcular()">
       </form>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: mandar a través de qué evento? un click, un blur?

Comment: al presionar el boton me aparesca la diferencia de fecha

Comment: Pues tu único error es que no estas invocando a JQuery y esto es necesario por que haces uso de la sintaxis: `$("#dias")` es decir debes invocar primero jquery y luego tu código JS

Comment: document.getElementById('#dias').val(contdias);   y si le pongo asi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes esta línea de código en tu ejercicio:

```
$('#dias').val(contdias);
```

Donde a través de la sintaxis de *JQuery* obtienes el elemento del DOM que se identifica por el id `dias`; sin embargo tu pregunta carece de la llamada a la librería en cuestión.

Que debería verse así:

- llamado a JQuery
- tu código JS que contiene a la función `calcular()`

Ahora como observación a tu pregunta, no ocupas JQuery mas que para invocar al elemento que tiene dicho id y asignarle un valor; entonces perfectamente puedes usar lo siguiente para que funcione igual

```
document.getElementById('dias').value = contdias;
```

- Se obtiene el elemento por medio del método `getElementById()`, donde no es necesario el símbolo de `#`
- Se hace uso de `.value` para indicar que se asignará un valor a la propiedad `value` de dicho elemento
- Igualamos el elemento obtenido con `contdias`

Comment: genial brother salio gracias

Comment: Sabras como bloquear las fechas pasadas de un input tipo date que se bloquen las fechas atras de la actual